# Sass styles messing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to SASS and i had found a animator code on Codepen website. This is it: [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/arthurcamara1/pen/LpNwyq?editors=1000)

```
.spinners
  margin: 60px auto
  .row
    height: 50px
    padding: 10px 0


/* ============================ */
/* VARIABLES                    */
/* ============================ */

$bar-width: 4px
$bar-height: 20px
$bar-color: #00B285
$bar-radius: 2px
```

I needed a bigger version of the animation and i edited the variables and that was perfectly working fine, until I needed a smaller version also.

So I added the same code again at the end and changed the respective classes. but the styles are getting bad. The HTML element at the top is getting bad while the following one is good.

Edited code by me: [Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGQWBp?editors=0100)

```
.sspinners
  margin: 60px auto
  .row
    height: 50px
    padding: 10px 0


/* ============================ */
/* VARIABLES                    */
/* ============================ */

$bar-width: 8px
$bar-height: 60px
$bar-color: #00B285
$bar-radius: 2px
```

Can you please tell why is that getting wrong? Or it is this way it is working? Please correct me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "Bad" & "Good" - Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are overriding your  variables. Only the last definition will be used for the whole document. You need to create new variables for each size eg. `$bar-width-large` `$bar-width-small` etc.

Comment: In the second link to codepen the first animation(in the same page) is looking bad(doesnt look like the second animation).

Comment: @Turnip I thought its like PHP, my bad. Thanks. Can you explain a bit more and post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding your variables.

SASS variables work like any other CSS property ie. Only the last definition will be used.

You need to define new variables for any properties that change for your different elements eg.

```
.spinners
  margin: 60px auto
  .row
    height: 50px
    padding: 10px 0


/* ============================ */
/* VARIABLES                    */
/* ============================ */

/* Default size */

$bar-width: 4px
$bar-height: 20px
$bar-color: #00B285
$bar-radius: 2px

/* large size*/

$bar-large-width: 8px
$bar-large-height: 60px

/* small size*/

$bar-small-width: 2px
$bar-small-height: 10px
```

After looking further at your code, you are also overriding all of your animation definitions and other CSS properties. You need to define a new version of each of these with a different name and using the new variables.

For example, your `bounce-bottom` animation needs to be redefined with a new name using the new variables:

```
@keyframes bounce-bottom
  0%
    height: 5px
    margin-top: $bar-height - 5px
  50%
    height: $bar-height
    margin-top: 0px
  100%
    height: 5px
    margin-top: $bar-height - 5px

  ... etc...
}

@keyframes bounce-bottom-large
  0%
    height: 5px
    margin-top: $bar-large-height - 5px
  50%
    height: $bar-large-height
    margin-top: 0px
  100%
    height: 5px
    margin-top: $bar-large-height - 5px

  ... etc...
}
```

You need to repeat this process for your *entire document* making sure that you aren't simply overriding your other definitions like you are currently.

Comment: Sorry to ask, can you edit the code? Changing was not working.

Comment: See update. There is too much code for me to fix it all. There should be enough info in my answer for you to do this yourself. If not, ask below.

Comment: Height does not change,width is okay. Updated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGQWBp?editors=0100

Comment: You are still overriding your animations.

Comment: I've edited the first for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reQLLE?editors=0100. I'm not going to do all of them.

Comment: I didnt notice the name after `@keyframes`. Sorry. Thanks for your  help.